# Synonymize [levenshtein-distance] -> [edit-distance]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

I created the [levenshtein-distance](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/levenshtein-distance) tag without knowing there was already an [edit-distance](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/edit-distance) out there. Can we make the one I created a synonym of the existing tag?

This will ensure any future users are using the correct tag. If we burn the one I just created, it will just get created again. It may also be easier to find than the existing tag.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I agree.. I have created the synonym. There is no reason to have both, and noone else other than a mod has enough rep in these tags to create synonyms for it.